# How to set the ticks on a logarithmic axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to draw nice ticks (scalar not exponential) on a logarithmic y-axis in matplotlib. In general I want to include the first value (`100`in this example) an work from there. But in some cases I get different tickers like below. I have found no clue as how to manage this. Is there an uncomplicated way to force matplotlib to start with a specific value and automatically select sensible tickers thereafter (in this example `120, 110, 100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20` would be nice).

My code:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import  ScalarFormatter, MaxNLocator
x = range(11)
y = [ 100.,   91.3700879 ,   91.01104689,   58.91189746,
     46.99501432,   55.3816625 ,   37.49715841,   26.55818469,
     36.34538328,   37.7811044 ,   47.45953131]
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(nbins=11, steps=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())
ax.plot(x,y)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set_ylim()`:

```
ax.set_ylim(20, 120)
```

[image]

This could be one way to make the limits depend on the y-data instead of hard-wiring them:

```
ymax = round(max(y), -1) + 10
ymin = max(round(min(y), -1) - 10, 0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

You can force the tick locations with `ax.set_yticks()`:

```
ymax = round(max(y), -1) + 20
ymin = max(round(min(y), -1) - 10, 0)
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
ax.set_yticks(range(int(ymin), int(ymax) + 1, 10))
ax.plot(x,y)
```

For:

```
y = [ 100. , 114.088362 , 91.14833261, 109.33399855, 73.34902925,
      76.43091996, 56.84863363, 65.34297117, 78.99411287, 70.93280065,
      55.03979689]
```

it produces this plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But how can I calculate sensible max and min values for an arbitrary case and how can I be sure that my starting value (`100` in the example above) is considered. I don't know the y-values beforehand. They can be almost any in the range [0, infinity[. The lowest value is limited to 0, but the highest is not limited (but probably won't be above a few millions at most)

Comment: You need to have `y` before you can plot. So `max(y)` will give you the maximum value. Than round to the next multiple of 10 or so.

Comment: No, unfortunately not. It works for this example, but if I replace `y=[...]`with `y = np.insert(np.cumprod(1 +(np.random.rand(10) - 0.5) / 1) * 100, 0, 100)` or special case `y = [ 100.0, 115.33050843,  171.99107963,  160.55507531, 228.98360629, 134.5789104 ,  162.94746556, 231.23097845, 295.907982  ,  289.18785165,  242.93483293]` it won't work. `100` is not included in the tickers of the special case.

Comment: I am very sorry, but won't work. For example with `y=[ 100.        ,  114.088362  ,   91.14833261,  109.33399855,  73.34902925,  76.43091996,   56.84863363,   65.34297117,  78.99411287,   70.93280065,   55.03979689]` ticker `100`is missing. Instead you get `..., 90, 99, 108, ...`. It is easy to find a solution for a special case, but very difficult for an arbitrary one.

Comment: Perfect. Works for me too. Thanks!